# Do I need AssemblyInfo while working with .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, csproj, assemblyinfo

Previously, `AssemblyInfo.cs` file was autocreated by Visual Studio to contain assembly-wide attributes, like AssemblyVersion, AssemblyName and so on.

In .NET Core and ASP.NET Core, `project.json` is responsible for holding most of that information.

So the question is: do I need to mark my assemblies with that attributes anymore? 
What traps can I get in if I will not mark assembly with that attributes?

Comment: Could you be more specific which attributes you miss and what you are afraid of?

Comment: I'm finding attributes redundant actually: `AssemblyVersion`(`version`), `AssemblyTitle`(`title`), `AssemblyDescription`(`copyright`).
I'm afraid of figuring some of attributes required, when these assemblies will be used in UWP or cross-platform solutions. Generally, I'd like to go on with `project.json` only.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[project.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json%20file) has replaced the `AssemblyInfo`.

`AssemblyVersionAttribute` is replaced by `version` property

```
version
Type: String
The Semver version of the project, also used for the NuGet package.
```

`AssemblyNameAttribute` is now the `name` property

```
name
Type: String
The name of the project, used for the assembly name as well as the name of the package. The top level folder name is used if this property is not specified.
```

and so on

---

**Update**: With the announcement of .NET Core Tools MSBuild, the `.csproj` has replaced the `project.json`. The `AssemblyInfo.cs` file is back, but most of the settings have been moved directly to `.csproj`. See related SO question for more details: [Equivalent to AssemblyInfo in dotnet core/csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42138418/2833802) :

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <Version>1.2.3.4</Version>
    <Authors>Author 1</Authors>
    <Company>Company XYZ</Company>
    <Product>Product 2</Product>
    <PackageId>MyApp</PackageId>
    <AssemblyVersion>2.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>3.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
    <Description>Description here</Description>
    <Copyright>Copyright</Copyright>
    <PackageLicenseUrl>License URL</PackageLicenseUrl>
    <PackageProjectUrl>Project URL</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageIconUrl>Icon URL</PackageIconUrl>
    <RepositoryUrl>Repo URL</RepositoryUrl>
    <RepositoryType>Repo type</RepositoryType>
    <PackageTags>Tags</PackageTags>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>Release</PackageReleaseNotes>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 12):

The `project.json` is not a direct replacement for the `AssemblyInfo.cs`, so there is still the need if you want to define some values you cannot provide in the `project.json`.

From the Issue https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2715 you can see, that in the beginning some parameters, like `title`, `description`, `copyright`, etc.  where taken to fill the fields for the generated nuget packages. With the issue 2715 the idea was born, that these values can "flow into the Assembly". So that you have not to configure these fields in two different places. So if you do not want to configure more than these paramters, the the `AssemblyInfo.cs` is not needed.

There are other fields like `[InternalsVisibleTo]` that can not be configured in `project.json`. So there are cases where there is still the need to define one.